# Array (c programming)

Tags: c

if there are n lockers, you’d better stop opening lockers once you get to argv[n - 1], since argv[n] doesn’t exist! (That or it belongs to someone else, in which case you still shouldn’t open it.)

please what thus an array of [n - 1] mean? thank you

Comment: Ah, the classic locker-based programming!

Comment: "please what thus an array of [n - 1] mean?" – what? please write in English. This is incomprehensible.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I believe that this is quite understandable (although bad) English. No need to overreact :)

Comment: @dmg I honestly don't get what he is asking.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant OK, but you can ask for clarifications, politely. Like a normal person. Obviously OP is new around here.

Comment: @dmg I didn't write anything impolite.

Answer (score 1):

> what does an array of [n - 1] mean?

It means you are trying to access value of array whose index is n-1.

So if you have array of size n where say n is 10 then on doing a[n-1] you are trying to access value of element which is at index 9 in array.

Read about [Array on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure).

Also see: [C Programming/Arrays Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Arrays)